# Pause/Resume Pandora from iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I'm writing an application that occasionally records the user's voice.  During recording, I would like the application to pause whatever music happens to be playing (pandora, ipod, etc) and when recording is finished, I want it to resume that music for the user.

Using MPMusicPlayerController's pause/play methods works with the iPod music.  In fact, 'pause' will pause Pandora without trouble also; however, 'play' resumes the iPod instead of Pandora.

Pointers to relevant documentation are appreciated.

Comment: i think that has more to do with how Pandora is implemented to deal with the pause

Comment: Yea... now that I think about it, I don't think I've heard Pandora resume after launching any application that takes over the audio queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped researching, but I don't believe there is a way to do this.

Comment: Same here. It seems impossible to use MPMusicPlayerController to control anything other than Apple's own iPod app.

Comment: I ended up faking it by muting the volume during recording (using MPMusicPlayerController) and then restoring the volume afterwards.